# Firefox for Windows prints table borders on first page only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a php report that generates populates, and prints a DIV element containing the following table:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; width:900;" id="PRINTAGEDWOTABLE">
<tbody>
<tr style="font-family:Arial; font-size:22; font-face: bold; text-decoration: underline;">
<th style="border:4px solid black; border-color: #000000;" colspan="5"         align="center">WORK ORDERS SEPTEMBER AND OLDER</th>
</tr>
<tr style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16; font-face: bold;">
<th style="border:4px solid black; padding: 5px;">WO#</th>
<th style="border:4px solid black; padding: 5px;">CUSTOMER</th>
<th style="border:4px solid black; padding: 5px;">EQUIPMENT</th>
<th style="border:4px solid black; padding: 5px;">JOB NOTES</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="6">
<br>
</th>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">123123</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SN#100181000</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">REPAIR - DETAILS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">2222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">Stock Orders</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">refurbish remote</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">22235</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">welding table (Fab)</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SERVICEVAN</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">NEW SERVICE VAN     MODIFICATIONS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">123123</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SN#100181858</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">REPAIR - DETAILS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">2222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">Stock Orders</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">refurbish remote</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">22235</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">welding table (Fab)</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SERVICEVAN</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">NEW SERVICE VAN    MODIFICATIONS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">123123</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SN#100181858</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">REPAIR - DETAILS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">2222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">Stock Orders</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">refurbish remote</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">22235</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">welding table (Fab)</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SERVICEVAN</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">NEW SERVICE VAN     MODIFICATIONS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">123123</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SN#100181858</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">REPAIR - DETAILS</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">2222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">Stock Orders</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">refurbish remote</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">22235</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">
</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">welding table (Fab)</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border:1px solid black; font-family:Arial ; font-size:16;">
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">222</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">DDD</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">SERVICEVAN</td>
<td style="text-align:center; padding:5px;">NEW SERVICE VAN     MODIFICATIONS</td>
</tr>
```

The div displays on screen correctly in Firefox for Windows and Linux, with single borders around each row.
It prints from Firefox 53 on Ubuntu correctly.
When printing From Firefox 56.01 on Windows, the first page prints with the correct borders. All additional pages print without borders.
I was using Firefox 53 on Windows previously, but updated to eliminate a potential version issue.
Both systems are printing to the same printer.
This has been working correctly up until a week ago. 
I have tried playing with the "border-collapse" property but it does not help.
Any insights would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, 55.0.2 on Ubuntu has the same problem. Since it worked in 53, I suspect it's a bug.

Comment: Would you kindly file a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Toolkit&component=Printing)?

Comment: @Dexter. I will file a bug report today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved in Firefox v57 beta.
Tested with beta version of Firefox v57 - Working

Already reported as:
Bug 1394249 - Borders of long table do not print after initial page

Closing